# Capture c# console application string in command variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, command

Is there any way i can output a string value from a c# application and capture it in a powershell or command variable?  I have a batch command job that runs a c# application.  I know i can capture an integer in `%ERRORLEVEL%` using `Environment.Exit()`.  I would like to have a variable that contains a string value from the c# application.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: `for /f  "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('csprogram.exe') do set "output=%%#"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your `c#` code you output the variable in the `console` with :

```
Console.WriteLine(YourVar);
```

then in the batch file :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('your_c#_file.exe') do set "$var=%%a"

echo result=%$var%
```

**Edit :**

If you have multiple variable as output!

**2 ways :**

**1 :**

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 set /a $Count=1
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('your_c#_file.exe') do 
   set "Var!$Count!=%%a"
   set/a $Count+=1
 )
```

And then you can use :

```
echo %Var1%
echo %Var2%
...
echo %Varx%
```

**2:**

Even better if you can output the variable from your `C#` code, directly like this :

```
name=John
lastname=Doe
```

then in the `batch` file you can directly `set` it like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('your_c#_file.exe') do set %%a
```

and then just :

```
echo %name%
echo %lastename%
```

The variable will directly have the right name !

Comment: How would this work if multiple variables are being output from the C# app?

Comment: Worked like a champ!  You are awesome!  Thank you so much!